# How to pass JSON type data as an input parameter in a Stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have one requirement wherein I need to pass JSON as an input parameter and process the data accordingly.

JSON data:

```
{
"Table name": "test_table",
"Column name":["column_1","column_2"],
"Column_value":["test_data","1"]
}
```

I need to write a procedure with this JSON as an input parameter.

Then based on the table name and column name it should insert the particular column value into the respective columns of a table.

Pseudo Code:

Store JSON in one table with the table structure as

```
   table_id |Table_name | Column_name | Column_value
```

Then pass table_name, column_name, and column_values  JSON format as input parameters.

Then extract tables, columns, and column_value from the input parameter and load in into the respective table.

Will this work? As I am not aware of how to handle JSON in a stored procedure or if anyone has any clue of how to start with this it would help me.

Tool Used: SQL Developer (18c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE load_data(
  i_json IN CLOB
)
IS
  v_obj      JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T(i_json);
  v_tbl      VARCHAR2(20)  := v_obj.get_string('Table name');
  v_cols     JSON_ARRAY_T  := v_obj.get_Array('Column name');
  v_vals     JSON_ARRAY_T  := v_obj.get_Array('Column_value');
  v_sql      CLOB := 'INSERT INTO ';
  v_sql_vals CLOB := ') VALUES (';
BEGIN
  v_sql := v_sql || DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(
                      DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_tbl, FALSE)
                    );
  v_sql := v_sql || ' (';
  FOR pos IN 0 .. v_cols.get_size() - 1
  LOOP
    IF pos > 0 THEN
      v_sql := v_sql || ',';
      v_sql_vals := v_sql_vals || ',';
    END IF;
    v_sql      := v_sql      || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME(v_cols.get_string(pos), FALSE);
    v_sql_vals := v_sql_vals || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(v_vals.get_string(pos));
  END LOOP;
  v_sql := v_sql || v_sql_vals || ')';
  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/
```

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "test_table" (
  "column_1" VARCHAR2(20),
  "column_2" NUMBER
);
```

Then you can use:

```sql
BEGIN
  load_data('{
"Table name": "test_table",
"Column name":["column_1","column_2"],
"Column_value":["test_data","1"]
}');
END;
/
```

And the table will contain:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "test_table";
```

> | column_1 | column_2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | test_data | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4dc979d9064c8224568e05a8707503e3)*

Comment: Thanks for this. It would be helpful if you can briefly explain the code. Seems little complex to me

Comment: @Vicky Which bit are you having trouble with (and have you tried adding in `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` statements to print the variables at various points in the procedure)? It is relatively simple as it just parses the JSON and then extracts the table name and then loops to find column identifier/value pairs and builds a dynamic SQL statement through string concatenation and uses `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run it at the end.

Comment: Okay. And why we have used DBMS_ASSERTS, ENQUOTE_NAME, ENQUOTE_LITERAL etc.

Comment: @Vicky To try to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Do you know how to parse json data and insert into tables based on their columns as key of the object?

Comment: @zemunkh You probably want to use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html) for that. However, your description of the problem is quite vague and you would be better to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statement, the example of the JSON and the expected output.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out it on my own. Thanks for your answer. This was really helpful.